# python3.X Issue with logging RotatingFileHandler while closing connections

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, python-logging

I wrote a script where i'm reading data from snowflake and updating in a cache. After the execution of script, snowflake is trying to auto close any connections left, while the connections are getting closed library is logging few details where i'm getting the below issue.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 69, in emit
    if self.shouldRollover(record):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 183, in shouldRollover
    self.stream = self._open()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1116, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
Call stack:
  File "~/.virtualenvs/test-ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 211, in __del__
    self.close(retry=False)
  File "~/.virtualenvs/test-ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 529, in close
    logger.info('closed')
Message: 'closed'
Arguments: ()
```

I tried removing RotatingFileHandler then there's no issue things are getting executed smoothly, i tried with python 3.5, 3.7 versions, the error is occurring in both the versions. Below is my logging configuration, what could i be possibly doing wrong.

```
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'cron_file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': '/var/log/my-project/crons.log',
            'mode': 'a',
            'maxBytes': 5242880,
            'backupCount': 10
        },
        'error_file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'level': 'WARN',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': '/var/log/my-project/error.log',
            'mode': 'a',
            'maxBytes': 5242880,
            'backupCount': 10
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        # root logger
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'cron_file', 'error_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'crons': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'cron_file', 'error_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the original call stack:

```py
Call stack:
  File "~/.virtualenvs/test-ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 211, in __del__
    self.close(retry=False)
  File "~/.virtualenvs/test-ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 529, in close
    logger.info('closed')
```

It tells you that it is trying to log when deleting an object out of memory.
There are two cases when `__del__` is called. You call `del object` or it is garbage collected. For the latter case, there are two times it happens. The first one is when the `refcount` reached `0`, and the second one is when the interpreter shutdowns, ie. your program exits.

This error happens while the interpreter is shutting down. At this time, objects get deleted, global namespace gets cleared. It means that `open` keyword was no longer exists when `__del__` calls it. Sometimes this error happens, sometimes it not. Because the garbage collector runs on its own thread, sometimes it deletes the global namespace before the log call.

So what can you do about it?

The obvious option is not to put logging inside `__del__`. But since it is someone else library, this option is not really viable. Another option is to remember to close the connection yourself when you no longer need it.
But there is more general solution, that is disabling the logging at the end of your program, right before the interpreter shutdown happens:

```py
import logging
# your code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # your code
    logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)    # levels less than or equal to Critical are ignored
    # EOF
```